# Automatically open an gmail addon card without user clicking on the addon icon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I am looking for a way (I understand does not really seem a good idea) to force my Gmail addon to automatically open a card and display the same.

Basically, the addon should check the current email's tags and then auto trigger some 'showPanel' of the addon.

I see [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743374/google-sheets-adds-on-open-automatically-when-user-opens-a-sheet-or-clicks-a-lin) about google sheets, but not getting how to go about this in the Gmail addon without user triggering it.

**Additional Chrome Extension way ??:**
If this is not something possible. I also have a chrome extension (which the users will have installed) clicking on a link created by the chrome extension can I somehow trigger the addon icons click event?

Apologies if this basic stuff, not able to find any direct useful info.

Comment: After a _very_ brief look at [restrictions in the docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions), it does not appear to be possible because you cannot use Apps Script triggers nor can you control the UI via client-side (ie, extensions) scripts.

Comment: @Brian. Yes. I think it probably not possible. Tried the chrome extension way but the addons seem to load way later with a different class name everytime

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension that allows you to automaticlly open an addon from Gmail, Calendar, Drive and Docs when you open the page in the browser.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-open-add-on/bcjnialkobgkdkbdclhdnbdcdgdcgdlo